# Cloud Functions for Firebase Multi-Path Update

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have been trying to migrate a multi path update that I had successfully created in the Android client previously into a cloud function.

For my app a user can submit a post (into "posts") that is associated with a car ("Cars"), e.g Porsche 911.

When a user submits a new post ("posts") I would like to update the popularity of the associated car in the "Cars" data and also all other car posts that are associated with the same car.

However when I run different versions of the js code as a cloud function it's not iterating through my "carPosts" data to create paths to each post that needs to be updated.

Can anyone help me out with the required js code for the cloud function please?

[image]

1. on new post get car key - I can get this to work
2. update car popularity by incrementing current popularity by 1 - I can get this to work
3. update all car posts that are associated with the car associated with new post? This doesn't work?

   ```
   var updKeys = {

           ["posts/-KIL0lbjplFBijxAJ75U/car/popularity"]: '1060',

           ["posts/-KIL0zBcU3Hjx6gf4Gxk/car/popularity"]: '1060',

           ["posts/-KIL1Wv6elvpf3T-0FVK/car/popularity"]: '1060',

           ["posts/-KIL2kUvY62qi46hb2t3/car/popularity"]: '1060',
       }
   ```

Comment: Can you provide your not working code ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the `update` function of Firebase. Something like below

```
ref.child('posts/${pushid}/car).update({popularity:1060})
```

This should automatically update all the relevant posts. But you may have to handle the `Promises` and subsequent `onWrite` events.